# Cannot access TFS Web Access - Class not registered error

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

I have been using Visual Studio 2012 with Microsoft Team Foundation Server for a while.

I noticed today, when I am in Team Explorer and I click on "Web Access", it throws an error that says "Class not registered". Everything else seems to work.

Any idea why I would be seeing this error?

Comment: Have you tried VS2012 Update 1 (released today)?

Comment: I missed that there was an update released today. I am installing it now to see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Add/Remove Programs and run a repair for Team Foundation Server, that should fix the issue.

Also, you should consider installing the latest quarterly update available for TFS.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30658